# How to loop through start urls in csv file scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

So basically it worked for some reason the first time I ran the spider but after that its only scraping one URL.

-My program is grabbing the parts i want to scrape from a list.

-Converts the list of parts too a URL from a file.

-Runs and grabs the data i want and inputs into a csv file.

The Problem:
Only getting output from one URL do not know where to go from here I have checked other resources and tried making a start_request. The result is still the same.

So basically how can I get it to use all the start_urls and iterate through each of them not just the last one?

Here is the Spider:

```
import csv
import xlrd
import scrapy

wb = xlrd.open_workbook(r'C:\Users\Jatencio\PycharmProjects\testy\test.xlsx')
ws = wb.sheet_by_index(0)
mylist = ws.col_values(0)
print(mylist)

li = []
for el in mylist:
    baseparts = el[:5]
    url1 = 'https://www.digikey.com/products/en/integrated-circuits-ics/memory/774?FV=-8%7C774%2C7%7C1&quantity=0&ColumnSort=0&page=1&k=' + baseparts + '&pageSize=500&pkeyword=' + baseparts
    li.append(url1)
final = list(set(li))


file = open('templist.csv','w+',newline='')
with file:
    write = csv.writer(file, delimiter =',')
    write.writerows(x.split(',') for x in final)

class DigikeSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'digike'
    allowed_domains = ['digikey.com']
    custom_settings = {
        "USER_AGENT": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36"

    }

    with open('templist.csv') as file:
        start_urls = [line.strip() for line in file]

    def parse(self, response):
        data = {}
        parts1 = []
        # parts=response.css('Table#productTable.productTable')
        for p in response.css('tbody#lnkPart > tr'):

            if p.css('td.tr-mfgPartNumber span::text').get() not in mylist:
                continue

            else:
                parts1 = p.css('td.tr-mfgPartNumber span::text').get()

            if p.css('td.tr-minQty.ptable-param span.desktop::text').get():
                quantity = p.css('td.tr-minQty.ptable-param span.desktop::text').get()
                quantity = quantity.strip()
                cleaned_quantity = int(quantity.replace(',', ''))
            else:
                quantity = 'No quantity'

            if p.css('td.tr-unitPrice.ptable-param center::text').get() == 'Active':
                p.css('td.tr-mfgPartNumber span::text').remove()

            else:
                pass

            if p.css('td.tr-unitPrice.ptable-param center::text').get() == 'Obsolete':
                p.css('td.tr-mfgPartNumber span::text').remove()

            else:
                pass

            if p.css('td.tr-unitPrice.ptable-param center::text').get() == 'Discontinued at Digi-Key':
                p.css('td.tr-mfgPartNumber span::text').remove()

            else:
                pass

            if p.css('td.tr-unitPrice.ptable-param span::text').get():
                price = p.css('td.tr-unitPrice.ptable-param span::text').get()
                cleaned_price = price.strip()
            else:
                price = 'No Price'

            if p.css('td.tr-qtyAvailable.ptable-param span.desktop::text').get():
                stock = p.css('td.tr-qtyAvailable.ptable-param span.desktop::text').get()
                cleaned_stock = stock.strip()

            else:
                pass
            if p.css('#part-status ::text').get():
                status = p.css('#part-status ::text').get()
                cleaned_status = status.strip()

            else:
                pass

            yield {
                'Part': parts1,
                'Quantity': cleaned_quantity,
                'Price': cleaned_price,
                'Stock': cleaned_stock,
                'Status': cleaned_status,

            }
```

OUTPUT

```
2020-07-30 10:12:11 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.digikey.com/products/en/integrated-circuits-ics/memory/774?FV=-8%7C774%2C7%7C1&quantity=0&ColumnSort=0&page=1&k=IS62L&pageSize=500&pkeyword=IS62L> (referer:
 None)
2020-07-30 10:12:11 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.digikey.com/products/en/integrated-circuits-ics/memory/774?FV=-8%7C774%2C7%7C1&quantity=0&ColumnSort=0&page=1&k=CY622&pageSize=500&pkeyword=CY622> (referer:
 None)
2020-07-30 10:12:11 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Spider error processing <GET https://www.digikey.com/products/en/integrated-circuits-ics/memory/774?FV=-8%7C774%2C7%7C1&quantity=0&ColumnSort=0&page=1&k=CY622&pageSize=500&pkeyword=CY622
> (referer: None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\jatencio\pycharmprojects\testy\venv\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\defer.py", line 120, in iter_errback
    yield next(it)
  File "c:\users\jatencio\pycharmprojects\testy\venv\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\python.py", line 346, in __next__
    return next(self.data)
  File "c:\users\jatencio\pycharmprojects\testy\venv\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\python.py", line 346, in __next__
    return next(self.data)
  File "c:\users\jatencio\pycharmprojects\testy\venv\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\spidermw.py", line 64, in _evaluate_iterable
    for r in iterable:
  File "c:\users\jatencio\pycharmprojects\testy\venv\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\offsite.py", line 29, in process_spider_output
    for x in result:
  File "c:\users\jatencio\pycharmprojects\testy\venv\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\spidermw.py", line 64, in _evaluate_iterable
    for r in iterable:
  File "c:\users\jatencio\pycharmprojects\testy\venv\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\referer.py", line 340, in <genexpr>
    return (_set_referer(r) for r in result or ())
  File "c:\users\jatencio\pycharmprojects\testy\venv\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\spidermw.py", line 64, in _evaluate_iterable
    for r in iterable:
  File "c:\users\jatencio\pycharmprojects\testy\venv\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\urllength.py", line 37, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
  File "c:\users\jatencio\pycharmprojects\testy\venv\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\spidermw.py", line 64, in _evaluate_iterable
    for r in iterable:
  File "c:\users\jatencio\pycharmprojects\testy\venv\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\depth.py", line 58, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
  File "c:\users\jatencio\pycharmprojects\testy\venv\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\spidermw.py", line 64, in _evaluate_iterable
    for r in iterable:
  File "C:\Users\Jatencio\PycharmProjects\testy\testdigi\testdigi\spiders\digike.py", line 93, in parse
    'Quantity': cleaned_quantity,
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'cleaned_quantity' referenced before assignment
2020-07-30 10:12:15 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.digikey.com/products/en/integrated-circuits-ics/memory/774?FV=-8%7C774%2C7%7C1&quantity=0&ColumnSort=0&page=1&k=IS62C&pageSize=500&pkeyword=IS62C> (referer:
 None)
2020-07-30 10:12:17 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.digikey.com/products/en/integrated-circuits-ics/memory/774?FV=-8%7C774%2C7%7C1&quantity=0&ColumnSort=0&page=1&k=IS62W&pageSize=500&pkeyword=IS62W> (referer:
 None)
2020-07-30 10:12:17 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.digikey.com/products/en/integrated-circuits-ics/memory/774?FV=-8%7C774%2C7%7C1&quantity=0&ColumnSort=0&page=1&k=CY621&pageSize=500&pkeyword=CY621> (referer:
 None)
2020-07-30 10:12:17 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.digikey.com/products/en/integrated-circuits-ics/memory/774?FV=-8%7C774%2C7%7C1&quantity=0&ColumnSort=0&page=1&k=CY621&pageSize=500&pkeyword=CY621>
{'Part': 'CY62128ELL-45SXIT', 'Quantity': 1000, 'Price': '$2.29429', 'Stock': '1,000 - Immediate', 'Status': 'Active'}
2020-07-30 10:12:17 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.digikey.com/products/en/integrated-circuits-ics/memory/774?FV=-8%7C774%2C7%7C1&quantity=0&ColumnSort=0&page=1&k=CY621&pageSize=500&pkeyword=CY621>
{'Part': 'CY62157EV30LL-45ZSXIT', 'Quantity': 1000, 'Price': '$6.44254', 'Stock': '2,000 - Immediate', 'Status': 'Active'}
2020-07-30 10:12:17 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.digikey.com/products/en/integrated-circuits-ics/memory/774?FV=-8%7C774%2C7%7C1&quantity=0&ColumnSort=0&page=1&k=CY621&pageSize=500&pkeyword=CY621>

2020-07-30 10:12:17 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Spider error processing <GET https://www.digikey.com/products/en/integrated-circuits-ics/memory/774?FV=-8%7C774%2C7%7C1&quantity=0&ColumnSort=0&page=1&k=CY621&pageSize=500&pkeyword=CY621
> (referer: None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\jatencio\pycharmprojects\testy\venv\lib\site-packages\parsel\selector.py", line 368, in remove
    parent = self.root.getparent()
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'getparent'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\jatencio\pycharmprojects\testy\venv\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\defer.py", line 120, in iter_errback
    yield next(it)
  File "c:\users\jatencio\pycharmprojects\testy\venv\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\python.py", line 346, in __next__
    return next(self.data)
  File "c:\users\jatencio\pycharmprojects\testy\venv\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\python.py", line 346, in __next__
    return next(self.data)
  File "c:\users\jatencio\pycharmprojects\testy\venv\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\spidermw.py", line 64, in _evaluate_iterable
    for r in iterable:
  File "c:\users\jatencio\pycharmprojects\testy\venv\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\offsite.py", line 29, in process_spider_output
    for x in result:
  File "c:\users\jatencio\pycharmprojects\testy\venv\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\spidermw.py", line 64, in _evaluate_iterable
    for r in iterable:
  File "c:\users\jatencio\pycharmprojects\testy\venv\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\referer.py", line 340, in <genexpr>
    return (_set_referer(r) for r in result or ())
  File "c:\users\jatencio\pycharmprojects\testy\venv\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\spidermw.py", line 64, in _evaluate_iterable
    for r in iterable:
  File "c:\users\jatencio\pycharmprojects\testy\venv\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\urllength.py", line 37, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
  File "c:\users\jatencio\pycharmprojects\testy\venv\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\spidermw.py", line 64, in _evaluate_iterable
    for r in iterable:
  File "c:\users\jatencio\pycharmprojects\testy\venv\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\depth.py", line 58, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
  File "c:\users\jatencio\pycharmprojects\testy\venv\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\spidermw.py", line 64, in _evaluate_iterable
    for r in iterable:
  File "C:\Users\Jatencio\PycharmProjects\testy\testdigi\testdigi\spiders\digike.py", line 55, in parse
    p.css('td.tr-mfgPartNumber span::text').remove()
  File "c:\users\jatencio\pycharmprojects\testy\venv\lib\site-packages\parsel\selector.py", line 164, in remove
    x.remove()
  File "c:\users\jatencio\pycharmprojects\testy\venv\lib\site-packages\parsel\selector.py", line 371, in remove
    raise CannotRemoveElementWithoutRoot(
parsel.selector.CannotRemoveElementWithoutRoot: The node you're trying to remove has no root, are you trying to remove a pseudo-element? Try to use 'li' as a selector instead of 'li::text' or '//li' instead of '//li/text()', for exampl
e.
2020-07-30 10:12:17 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2020-07-30 10:12:17 [scrapy.extensions.feedexport] INFO: Stored csv feed (40 items) in: DigiKeyPartsList.csv
```

print(start_urls): ['https://www.digikey.com/products/en/integrated-circuits-ics/memory/774?FV=-8%7C774%2C7%7C1&quantity=0&ColumnSort=0&page=1&k=IS62C&pageSize=500&pkeyword=IS62C', 'https://www.digikey.com/products/en/integrated-circuits-ics/memory/774?F
V=-8%7C774%2C7%7C1&quantity=0&ColumnSort=0&page=1&k=IS62L&pageSize=500&pkeyword=IS62L', 'https://www.digikey.com/products/en/integrated-circuits-ics/memory/774?FV=-8%7C774%2C7%7C1&quantity=0&ColumnSort=0&page=1&k=IS62W&pageSize=500&pke
yword=IS62W', 'https://www.digikey.com/products/en/integrated-circuits-ics/memory/774?FV=-8%7C774%2C7%7C1&quantity=0&ColumnSort=0&page=1&k=CY621&pageSize=500&pkeyword=CY621', 'https://www.digikey.com/products/en/integrated-circuits-ics
/memory/774?FV=-8%7C774%2C7%7C1&quantity=0&ColumnSort=0&page=1&k=CY622&pageSize=500&pkeyword=CY622']

New Output

```
2020-07-30 12:51:31 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 2.2.1 started (bot: testdigi)
2020-07-30 12:51:31 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.5.2.0, libxml2 2.9.5, cssselect 1.1.0, parsel 1.6.0, w3lib 1.22.0, Twisted 20.3.0, Python 3.8.3 (tags/v3.8.3:6f8c832, May 13 2020, 22:37:02) [MSC v.1924 64 bit (AMD64)], pyO
penSSL 19.1.0 (OpenSSL 1.1.1g  21 Apr 2020), cryptography 3.0, Platform Windows-10-10.0.17134-SP0
2020-07-30 12:51:31 [scrapy.utils.log] DEBUG: Using reactor: twisted.internet.selectreactor.SelectReactor
2020-07-30 12:51:31 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings:
{'BOT_NAME': 'testdigi',
 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'testdigi.spiders',
 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['testdigi.spiders'],
 'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 '
               '(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36'}
2020-07-30 12:51:31 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet Password: 4abf97dccc166f2d
2020-07-30 12:51:31 [py.warnings] WARNING: c:\users\jatencio\pycharmprojects\testy\venv\lib\site-packages\scrapy\extensions\feedexport.py:210: ScrapyDeprecationWarning: The `FEED_URI` and `FEED_FORMAT` settings have been deprecated in
favor of the `FEEDS` setting. Please see the `FEEDS` setting docs for more details
  exporter = cls(crawler)

2020-07-30 12:51:31 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.feedexport.FeedExporter',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
2020-07-30 12:51:32 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2020-07-30 12:51:32 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2020-07-30 12:51:32 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2020-07-30 12:51:32 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2020-07-30 12:51:32 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2020-07-30 12:51:32 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2020-07-30 12:51:33 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.digikey.com/products/en/integrated-circuits-ics/memory/774?FV=-8%7C774%2C7%7C1&quantity=0&ColumnSort=0&page=1&k=IS62L&pageSize=500&pkeyword=IS62L> (referer:
 None)
2020-07-30 12:51:33 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.digikey.com/products/en/integrated-circuits-ics/memory/774?FV=-8%7C774%2C7%7C1&quantity=0&ColumnSort=0&page=1&k=IS62C&pageSize=500&pkeyword=IS62C> (referer:
 None)
2020-07-30 12:51:33 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.digikey.com/products/en/integrated-circuits-ics/memory/774?FV=-8%7C774%2C7%7C1&quantity=0&ColumnSort=0&page=1&k=CY622&pageSize=500&pkeyword=CY622> (referer:
 None)
2020-07-30 12:51:33 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.digikey.com/products/en/integrated-circuits-ics/memory/774?FV=-8%7C774%2C7%7C1&quantity=0&ColumnSort=0&page=1&k=CY622&pageSize=500&pkeyword=CY622>
{'Part': 'CY62256NLL-55ZXIT', 'Quantity': 'No quantity', 'Price': '$1.11989', 'Stock': '0', 'Status': 'Obsolete'}
2020-07-30 12:51:33 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.digikey.com/products/en/integrated-circuits-ics/memory/774?FV=-8%7C774%2C7%7C1&quantity=0&ColumnSort=0&page=1&k=IS62W&pageSize=500&pkeyword=IS62W> (referer:
 None)
2020-07-30 12:51:33 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.digikey.com/products/en/integrated-circuits-ics/memory/774?FV=-8%7C774%2C7%7C1&quantity=0&ColumnSort=0&page=1&k=CY622&pageSize=500&pkeyword=CY622>
{'Part': 'CY62256VNLL-70ZXIT', 'Quantity': 'No quantity', 'Price': 'No Price', 'Stock': '0', 'Status': 'Obsolete'}
2020-07-30 12:51:33 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.digikey.com/products/en/integrated-circuits-ics/memory/774?FV=-8%7C774%2C7%7C1&quantity=0&ColumnSort=0&page=1&k=CY622&pageSize=500&pkeyword=CY622>
{'Part': 'CY62256NLL-55SNXIT', 'Quantity': 'No quantity', 'Price': 'No Price', 'Stock': '0', 'Status': 'Obsolete'}
2020-07-30 12:51:33 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.digikey.com/products/en/integrated-circuits-ics/memory/774?FV=-8%7C774%2C7%7C1&quantity=0&ColumnSort=0&page=1&k=CY622&pageSize=500&pkeyword=CY622>
{'Part': 'CY62256VNLL-70SNXIT', 'Quantity': 'No quantity', 'Price': 'No Price', 'Stock': '0', 'Status': 'Obsolete'}
2020-07-30 12:51:34 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.digikey.com/products/en/integrated-circuits-ics/memory/774?FV=-8%7C774%2C7%7C1&quantity=0&ColumnSort=0&page=1&k=CY621&pageSize=500&pkeyword=CY621> (referer:
 None)
{'Part': 'CY62148EV30LL-45ZSXIT', 'Quantity': 1000, 'Price': 'No Price', 'Stock': '0', 'Status': 'Active'}
2020-07-30 12:51:34 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2020-07-30 12:51:34 [scrapy.extensions.feedexport] INFO: Stored csv feed (46 items) in: DigiKeyPartsList.csv
2020-07-30 12:51:34 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 2145,
 'downloader/request_count': 5,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 5,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 289446,
 'downloader/response_count': 5,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 5,
 'elapsed_time_seconds': 2.311786,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 30, 16, 51, 34, 681758),
 'item_scraped_count': 46,
 'log_count/DEBUG': 51,
 'log_count/INFO': 11,
 'log_count/WARNING': 1,
 'response_received_count': 5,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 5,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 5,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 5,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 5,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 30, 16, 51, 32, 369972)}
2020-07-30 12:51:34 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)

(venv) C:\Users\Jatencio\PycharmProjects\testy\testdigi\testdigi>
```

Comment: Im getting an (referer: None) on each url that is not being run in my output.

Comment: What is the value stored in `start_urls` can you check? (Printing, logging or using a debugger)

Comment: @renatodvc I added it to the above ^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now, with the execution logs I can tell you there are two issues in the spider, none seem to be related to to the `start_urls`.

#### First exception:

```
File "C:\Users\Jatencio\PycharmProjects\testy\testdigi\testdigi\spiders\digike.py", line 93, in parse
    'Quantity': cleaned_quantity,
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'cleaned_quantity' referenced before assignment
```

You are referencing the `cleaned_quantity` before defining it.  The problem is here:

```
        if p.css('td.tr-minQty.ptable-param span.desktop::text').get():
            quantity = p.css('td.tr-minQty.ptable-param span.desktop::text').get()
            quantity = quantity.strip()
            cleaned_quantity = int(quantity.replace(',', ''))
        else:
            quantity = 'No quantity'
```

If your if statement resolve to false, cleaned_quantity is never defined, and will raise an error when you try to assemble your item:

```
        yield {
            'Part': parts1,
            'Quantity': cleaned_quantity,
            'Price': cleaned_price,
            'Stock': cleaned_stock,
            'Status': cleaned_status,
        }
```

This is happening in a few iterations only, not all.

#### Second exception:

```
 File "C:\Users\Jatencio\PycharmProjects\testy\testdigi\testdigi\spiders\digike.py", line 55, in parse
    p.css('td.tr-mfgPartNumber span::text').remove()
[...]
 File "c:\users\jatencio\pycharmprojects\testy\venv\lib\site-packages\parsel\selector.py", line 371, in remove
    raise CannotRemoveElementWithoutRoot(
parsel.selector.CannotRemoveElementWithoutRoot: The node you're trying to remove has no root, are you trying to remove a pseudo-element? Try to use 'li' as a selector instead of 'li::text' or '//li' instead of '//li/text()', for example.
```

The problem here is that you are using `.remove()` method in what parsel call a pseudo-element, you can only use to remove the actual element from the HTML tree, so I believe this should solve the issue:

Change this:

```
p.css('td.tr-mfgPartNumber span::text').remove()
```

to this:

```
p.css('td.tr-mfgPartNumber span').remove()
```

**This is the case for ALL lines you are using the `remove` method.**

Please let me know if this solved your issue.

Comment: Thank you, this helped a lot but one problem arises now its only pulling data for two urls not all of them. I get this error message:  ScrapyDeprecationWarning: The `FEED_URI` and `FEED_FORMAT` settings have been deprecated in
favor of the `FEEDS` setting. Please see the `FEEDS` setting docs for more details
  exporter = cls(crawler)

Comment: How are you executing the spider? Did you check those settings in your `settings.py`? Can you add the whole execution log?

Comment: Updated the output I used scrapy crawl digike to exccute

Comment: According to your logs all the 5 pages in your `start_urls` were successfully crawled. Some of those pages didn't scrape anything, which means that either the data isnt there or the selectors are not appropriate to find the data you want. There is no more errors in your execution.

Comment: Thanks, I will look at my selectors again.